# Doctrine2 challenge, I Have OneToMany, but NOT ManyToOne,

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Have a messaging system, where messages can belong to a consultation, but it dosnt have to. All consultations do have 1 or more messages though...

My entities have been generated by Doctrine automatically, but `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema` fails misreably...

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon' mapping is invalid:
* The association Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon#meldinger refers to the owning side field Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger#konsulatsjon which is not defined as association, but as field.
* The association Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon#meldinger refers to the owning side field Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger#konsulatsjon which does not exist.

[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

Definition of the associations in question:
From Messages / Meldinger:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="konsulatsjon", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Konsultasjon", inversedBy="konsultasjonid")
 */
 private $konsulatsjon;
```

From my "Parent" Consultation Konsultasjon:

```
 /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger", mappedBy="konsulatsjon", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
 private $meldinger;
```

My konsultasjon is mapped with foreign trigger, but not my messages (because many of the konsultasjon is NULL).

Also there is wery little I can do about spelling, as this is a legacy and rather messy app...

Please let me know if you need anything else, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]
Removed @var and @collumn in Messages (Meldinger) as sugested in the comments, ended up with this result:

```
  vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon#meldinger and Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger#konsulatsjon are inconsistent with each other.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger' mapping is invalid:
* The association Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger#konsulatsjon refers to the inverse side field Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon#konsultasjonid which is not defined as association.
* The association Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger#konsulatsjon refers to the inverse side field Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon#konsultasjonid which does not exist.
* The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon'.

  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
  Column name `id` referenced for relation from Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger towards Legetimen\Entity\Konsultasjon does not exist.

orm:validate-schema
```

Konsultasjon ID:

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="konsultasjonid", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false,          unique=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
 private $konsultasjonid;
```

Messages ID / Meldinger

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="meldingerid", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
 private $meldingerid;
```

Comment: Your `$konsulatsjon` can't be a integer, because you map it to the class `Konsultasjon`. You should remove the whole `@Column`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but it did not help, rather it produced more errors... Any idea? (Edited my post to reflect the changes you suggested)...

Comment: You probably forget to add ``@Id`` for ``$id`` property in ``Konsultasjon`` (errors say so)

Comment: I wish :/ But they are both there... Please see my post, I have updated it with the ID annotations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't use `$id` as Primary Key of your entity, you have to use `JoinColumn` annotation to configure relation between entities. [JoinColumn](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn).

If you want to change column name of relation property you need to use `JoinColumn` instead of `Column` annotation.

```
class Meldinger { 
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="meldingerid", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     private $meldingerid;

     /**
      * @var integer
      *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Konsultasjon", inversedBy="meldinger")
      * @JoinColumn(name="konsulatsjon", referencedColumnName="konsulatsjonid")
      */
     private $konsulatsjon;
 }

 class Konsultasjon { 
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="konsultasjonid", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $konsultasjonid;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Legetimen\Entity\Meldinger", mappedBy="konsulatsjon", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER") 
     * @JoinColumn(name="meldinger", referencedColumnName="meldingerid")
     */
    private $meldinger;
 }
```

PS.
I also corrected `@ManyToOne`parameters for `Meldinger`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
(Only change I did from this was referencedColumnName="konsulatsjonid" should be konsultasjonid ;)